# Android Fragments to return to last know state

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a navgation drawer in Android to select between different fragments.
Fragment A has user interface.
Fragment B has bluetooth scan.

User goes to Fragment B, does a scan and connect to device, shows its connected to a device

Goes to Fragment A.

On returning back to Fragment B it replaces screen as brand new and not connected

Is there a way of the fragment to remember its last state before switching to another Fragment. Or is this better as a activity?

Apologies if this has been asked before or a basic question.  First time using Fragments and getting the hang of them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  in the code for the navigation drawer you have

```
        settingsfragment = new SettingsFragment();
        FragmentManager settingsManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        settingsManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.fragment_area,
                settingsfragment,
                settingsfragment.getTag()
        ).commit();
```

however, this generates a new fragment each time from the first line of code.

If it gets changed to the following

```
            if (settingsfragment == null)
            settingsfragment = new SettingsFragment();

        FragmentManager settingsManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        settingsManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.fragment_area,
                settingsfragment,
                "FRAG_TAG"
        ).commit();
```

This will check to see if the layout has already been created and will place it back when called on.

Thank you to all other comments and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do by using SaveInstaceState and OnRestoreState, you also need backstack manager, but first give me your code as an example,

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying,  I have know about saveInstanceState.  The problem is, when using a navigation drawer, switching between fragments, onSaveInstanceState does not get called. Unless I am doing something complete wrong to normal

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to: when addint a new Fragment, uses:

```
Fragment f = new FragmentB();
fragTransaction.addToBackstack(null);
fragTransaction.replace(layout, f);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

the default onReturnPressed will pop the stack back to your fragment.

If you want to control you just call

```
getFragmentManager().popStackBack();
```

Comment: Hi Marcos,  yes this did work, however from a navigation drawer if you select B, then select A, when going back to B its still a new layout when I want it to know the last layout

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's look like you are creating a new instance of the Fragment always when you click in "switch fragment A to B".

I suggest you to use a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) componente instead to better handle the fragments and not to lost the state

Comment: Can you use the navigation drawer with ViewPager?

Comment: ViewPager is just to handle the fragments using a FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: You can suitch the fragments in Nav Drawer Itens Click using vpPager.setCurrentItem(1) for example. Look this link https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter#setup-fragmentpageradapter